# Bluetooth server application accepting connections from mobile devices

Tags: .net, windows, bluetooth, wrapper

I'd like to develop a desktop application (on Windows, and preferably on .NET) that accepts bluetooth connections from mobile devices, that would then send commands to this application.

I've never worked with bluetooth before. I've looked for open-source examples of such applications, but I had no luck. I've actually found on Microsoft a managed (.NET) wrapper for the bluetooth stack on Windows CE, but wasn't able to use it on my Windows 7.

Do you know of any good texts discussing this topic? Any other source of information on the subject? Where should I start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quick VB code sample showing use of our 32feet.NET shared-source Bluetooth (and OBEX and IrDA) library:

```
Dim lsnr As New BluetoothListener(MyConsts.MyServiceUuid)
lsnr.Start()
' Now accept new connections, perhaps using the thread pool to handle each
Dim conn As New BluetoothClient = lsnr.AcceptBluetoothClient()
Dim peerStream As Stream = conn.GetStream()
...
```

That's from the user guide at http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/32feet.NET%20--%20User%20Guide.html

Get the library from http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Hope you find it useful.  Any question, ask here or at our forums. http://inthehand.com/forums/default.aspx?GroupID=29